# DropdownButton Menu item width

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

is there any to reduce the width of the dropdownbutton menu widow width after clicking the dropdownbutton? only want to change the width of the window after clicking dropdownbutton and keeping the dropdown button's isExpanded = true. I tried wrapping it with the container and giving width but it also change the width of the dropdown button as well. I don't want to use any external package. You can see in the output image i want to remove the red square space from the dropdown.  any suggestions or solution will be super helpful....thanks in advance

```
return Container(
   // width: 300.0,
   
      child: DropdownButton(
isExpanded = true,
        value: selectedname,
        items: listOfDropdownMenuItems.map(
          (name) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: name,
            child: Text(
              name,
             
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),),
        onChanged:(newValue) {
          setname(newValue!);
        },
        underline: Container(),
      ),
    ),
);
```

[output image:]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FISMs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to solve your issue

```
  Widget customDropDown(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      /// Set the width of the DropdownButton
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            /// here you can control border and it's radius
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  _selectedItem.isNotEmpty ? _selectedItem : 'Select an item',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        offset: Offset(0, 40), // Adjust the offset as needed
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
          PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: 'Option 1',
            child: Container(
              width: 120, // Set the width of the PopupMenuItem
              child: Text('Option 1'),
            ),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: 'Option 2',
            child: Container(
              width: 120, // Set the width of the PopupMenuItem
              child: Text('Option 2'),
            ),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: 'Option 3',
            child: Container(
              width: 120, // Set the width of the PopupMenuItem
              child: Text('Option 3'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        onSelected: (String value) {
          /// TODO Your Method
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, Rifat for your response. The problem with PopupMenuButton is that I cannot navigate inside the list using arrow keys(up/down) that's why i am using Dropdownbutton to have that functionality